# Dynamically set button controller/action in telerik grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I have an ASP.NET4 MVC app and am using [Telerik Grid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid).

I want to have a View button in the second column and I need to set the controller based on the MyViewModel.Controller property. How do I do that?

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<MyViewModel>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding
        .Ajax()
            .Select("_Ajax", "Home"))
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.Id))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.DisplayName);
        columns.Command(commands =>
        {
            commands.Custom("viewButton")
                .Text("View")
                .Ajax(false)
                .Action("Index", "MyViewModel.Controller");            
        });   
    })
    .ClientEvents(events => events.OnRowDataBound("Grid_onRowDataBound"))
    .Pageable(pager => pager.PageSize(30))
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `.ClientTemplate()` and made the column unfilterable and unsortable to remove the icon at the top of the column.

```
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.DisplayName).Width(200);        
        columns.Bound(o => o.Controller)
            .ClientTemplate("<a href='/<#= Controller #>' class='t-button'>View</a>")
            .Filterable(false)
            .Sortable(false)
            .Title("");         
    })
```